# yii sorting CListView with dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

So I have a CListView, that I can sort using the attributes I've set in sortableAttributes, this is fine when it's just ASC and DESC sorting. But I also want to sort the CListView by a category. In my model I have a category, ranging from 0-8. I've made a dropdown select that shows the categories.

What I would like to do is update my CListView when an option in the dropdown is selected, I could write my own jQuery code for this, but I'm guessing there is some smart yii way of doing this.

Thanks

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'sortableAttributes'=>array('views','create_time','release_time'),
    'id'=>'#videos',
    'itemView'=>$view,
    'pager'=>array('cssFile'=>'/css/pager.css'),
)); ?>
```

Comment: how do you want to sort once the category is selected? let's say category selected is 4, what then?

Comment: I want to show only the items where category is equal to 4. Like adding this to the URI will do it.

    /index?Video[category]=4

Comment: The thing is that I want to update the CListView with AJAX, just like my sortableAttributes does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much toiling:

There are two things you have to do. First, we need the modified data from the server,
for that you could modify your model's search function, because that is the one providing the dataprovider for the CListView.

So in the `search()` function of your model you could add an `if` condition to modify the `$criteria` of the dataprovider, for example something like this:

```
public function search() {

     // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
     // should not be searched.

     $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

     // added the following if condition to modify the criteria to include only videos of a certain category
     if (isset($_GET['category']))
           $criteria->compare('category',$_GET['category'],true);// my category is string, hence the third attribute
     else
           $criteria->compare('category',$this->category,true);// we need the else part, coz the search function is used for actual searching also, for instance in gridview filters/search

     $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
     // your other attributes follow    

     return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
     ));
}
```

**Note**: I'm not sure if it is absolutely necessary to sanitize $_GET['category'] before comparing.

Second we need to update the CListView for which we can use its function `$.fn.yiiListView.update`. So for example:

```
<div id="categoryupdating">
<?php 
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('dropit', '', 
     array('1'=>'Cateogry1','2'=>'Category2','3'=>'Category3','4'=>'Category4'),
     array('onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiListView.update('videos', {url: '".Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action')."?category='+$('#dropit option:selected').val()})"));
?>
</div>
```

Here ofcourse you should be populating the data for the dropdown dynamically using probably such functions as `CHtml::listData` , and the controller/action should be the controller/action of the CListView.

Check out the *jquery.yiilistview.js* file to know more about yii's listview widget's javascript functions.

**Note**: $.fn.yiiListView.update takes the `id` of the listview and the `url` to call for update, as parameters.

**Edit**: added `else` condition also, since the search function is used for actual searching in gridview, and elsewhere.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the input. I figured out a way to do it myself tho. Just wasn't able to post how last night, because of the 8hour waiting period. Sorry for wasting your time :( Hopefully it will be helpful for others in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, this is how I ended up doing it.

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('category', "
$('#category').change(function(){
    $.fn.yiiListView.update('videos', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
});
");
```

The important part is the id in the htmlOptions of the dropDownList, as you cannot use "Video[category]" as the id for the $.fn.yiiListView.update function. But it is needed as the name of the select, to be able to use the already existing search ability.

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList(
    'Video[category]',
    0,
    Lookup::items('VideoCategory'),
    array('id' => 'category')
); ?>
```